# Django change admin inline delete checkbox

Tags: python, django, admin, inline

I am trying to change the delete checkbox for a inline model on the `django-admin` page.

Until now, one can check the box and after pressing save it will be deleted. But I want some button (or this "x" like when you click "Add another...") that when it is pressed, it deletes immediately.

I would prefer not editing the admin templates and including a ton of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [django-dynamic-formset](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset)? The library itself is a "ton of JavaScript" but at least it won't require much JavaScript work from your end.

Usage instructions are [here](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset/blob/master/docs/usage.rst#working-with-inline-formsets).

Comment: It would be nice, if I do not need a 3rd party package.